# What is the most efficient way to use like on join statement?

Tags: mysql

When using join statement, I would like to join the tables using like condition.
What is the most efficient way to do that?

Using `fielda like CONCAT ('%', fieldb, '%')` does not seem to be very efficient

Comment: Yes, it is very inefficient as it kills whatever index define on the column. The best way to do is to recreate the table or something like add a new column, put an index on that, and do the joins again.

Comment: You can use anything you want for a join condition. What it boils down to in the end is a true/false value. If the join result is true, the DB will perform the join on the two rows being considered. if false, the row combination is skipped. Given you provided no table structure/details/requirements at all, we cannot tell you what the answer is.

Comment: What application semantics encourage you to use %+field+%? If you give more specifics about what you want to do, more help can be given by the community.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 wild char renders the index useless, what you could do is removing the one in the front, than mysql will still use the index to find whatever your searching for. If you don't have a index, to create one use the following code:

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename(columnname);
```

And then change the query to

```
fielda like CONCAT (fieldb, '%')
```

to make use of the index, other things to consider is the column a text field or simple just a varchar field, cause if it contains longer text you should consider a fulltext search.

Here is a more indepth article on the subject with sample's and good explanation etc.

http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do actual searching, your are going to want to learn how to do full text indexes and queries. I'm sure you can find some primers on the subject by searching google, but here is the MySQL docs on it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html